# How can I use one For loop in another in PHP?

Tags: php, for-loop, random

I have this code:

```
$surse = "1A23vEqwertyu4_56789QWERTh_jklzYUIOPAxc_vSDFGHVBNMiopa_sdfgbnmJKLZXC"; 
    for ($i = 0; $i <50; $i++) 
    { 
        $result_image[$i] = $surse[rand(0,60)];
    }
```

to create random file name with:

```
$result_image = time().implode("",$result_image).'.jpg';
```

for example.

But I need create random another file name inside it like:

```
$surse = "1A23vEqwertyu4_56789QWERTh_jklzYUIOPAxc_vSDFGHVBNMiopa_sdfgbnmJKLZXC"; 
    for ($i = 0; $i <50; $i++) 
    { 
        $result_image[$i] = $surse[rand(0,60)];

        for ($e = 0; $e <=2; $e++) 
        {
            $png.$i[$i] = $surse[rand(0,60)];
        }
    }
```

but this echo some error:

```
Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in E:\xampp\htdocs\.......
```

Where is the problem?

PS:
**I need create one PNG file in first loop and some PNG in 2th loop, my code have error,I know, please dont - to me!**

**Code Edit in $result_image = time().implode("",$result_image).'.jpg'; section.**

Comment: What is `$png.$i[$i]` supposed to be?

Comment: Plus, where does `$result_image_surse` come into play?

Comment: i need to create one png file in first loop and some png file with 2th loop.

Comment: Where is this variable: `$result_image_surse`?

Comment: Your `implode()` error is likely because the `$result_image_surse` doesn't exist.

Comment: As i say, this variable can create, but $png1,$png2,%png3 and etc. No, i need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what you are really looking for but this is about the best I can come up with with your explanation:

```
function Randomize($ext = 'jpg', $start = 0,$end = 50)
    {
        $surse = "1A23vEqwertyu4_56789QWERTh_jklzYUIOPAxc_vSDFGHVBNMiopa_sdfgbnmJKLZXC";
        for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++) { 
                $result_image[$i] = $surse[rand(0,60)];
            }

        return time().implode($result_image).".$ext";
    }

for ($i = 0; $i <3; $i++) { 
   $image[$i]   =   Randomize();

    for ($e = 0; $e <=2; $e++) {
        $png[$i][$e] = Randomize('png');
    }
}

print_r($image);
print_r($png);
```

**Will produce:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1417753677nO3515jHATr2_pAahNAGNHloTq6VT_tTn__1lqHvYsqHVextd4.jpg
    [1] => 1417753677cQqHYDcrl2OBqOTApA8YqrfsEn2WwiRVrzYSueoDyTk7gp_i_y.jpg
    [2] => 1417753677sqAv6VOwRq6M_BfWcG3FfdsddbSGMqkG4zRl6gx_3akD_T37eq.jpg
)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1417753677sGgROWzoq_6776Yf6n2AvIfy8D9dp5eVbErIj_TOUvoifEV4WM.png
            [1] => 14177536775_EyxSafAHyGYtivG78wooNDSH3_gh54ocTk87T_AAcUBkyYHz.png
            [2] => 1417753677_AQj81yWjrBFExQVE_2zIvqyA__NTT731xz8cD_Eo_N43eneB2.png
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1417753677Q1Q6sD6g3TNjtgfScriko1a88ity_3EnvF6bhUfkdHdqDaBQAA.png
            [1] => 1417753677MpxStdzWqrhlelyTjAfTvaenbopVt_EbHb_d_r619SzkrSax7M.png
            [2] => 1417753677AEDrWvn4hrqBepVNNvg3S6HtHspxUe_IzwFpNDEupyn13VNo_H.png
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 14177536771vAdng_SSFNr_1_izdBqOin2Y_jPdPSd_Fp_vH9WkwzseeG_vz.png
            [1] => 1417753677Vc9HSoRwh9DE5QMqblp8i9_94Pkf4U_btVFoAqb1hvqS1sBnTc.png
            [2] => 141775367784gGIt8AwUOIzH94AsQOsH41__du49iUIB5EgOwvEScAhfMAoe.png
        )
)
```

Comment: very well, but it seems create Associative Arrays for png file,i need Numeric array, how?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want the output to look like?

Comment: Do you want 50 jpegs and 50 png in two different arrays?

Comment: i want to draw row of text, and i need to create 2 JPG file and some  PNG for each row of text,

Comment: your code work very well, but i don't need all of these png and jpg file

Comment: Well it's looping 50. Just reduce the loop amount to whatever you want. For every 1 jpg it is producing 3 pngs.